# Validation Rule on Pre-Chat Intake form

Tags: visual-workflow, validation-rule, omnichannel, pre-chat

I'm seeking a way to implement validation for the "Phone" field within the standard Pre-Chat form. While I've successfully added a 10-digit validation rule to the "Phone" field on the Contact object itself, it doesn't seem to apply to the same field on the Pre-Chat form where users initially provide their phone numbers before a contact record is created.

Is there a method to ensure the validation rule also functions within the Pre-Chat form, ensuring consistent data quality even before contact creation?

Thank you for your guidance!

Answer (score 0):

Include JavaScript code to validate the phone number format before submitting the form.

Because JS will handle the part that you want to show/validate on UI.
Something like below -

function validatePhoneNumber() {
var phoneNumber = document.getElementById('phone').value;

```
        if (phoneNumber.length !== 10 || isNaN(phoneNumber)) {
            alert('Please enter a valid 10-digit phone number.');
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Note: always check if a variable is null *before* checking a property on the variable.